# How to convert a string separated by square brackets with comma into valid json object in php?

Tags: php, json

I got a specific string that I want to convert into a JSON object in PHP

**The string is:** `['Spring', '>30'], ['JPA', '>30'], ['Hibernate', '>30'], 1`

**Here is what I tried so far:**

`$catwidfieldval = "['Spring', '>30'], ['JPA', '>30'], ['Hibernate', '>30'], 1";`
`$jsonrt = json_decode ($catwidfieldval, true);`
`var_dump ($jsonrt);`

**Result of above code:** NULL

**This is what I want to achieve:**

`[ 0:[ 0:Spring 1:>30 ], 1:[ 0:JPA 1:>30 ], 2:[ 0:Hibernate 1:>30 ] ]`

**Note:** Last Index is not required in JSON object eg like 1 in the above string

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The formats given is no valid JSON. So you need to parse it yourself.

You could go with a regex to find the content between the square brackets. Then loop over those to extract the values between the quotes.

```
$string  = "['Spring', '>30'], ['JPA', '>30'], ['Hibernate', '>30'], 1";
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $match) {
    $matches2 = [];
    preg_match_all('/\'(.*?)\'/', $match, $matches2);
    $parts[] = "$index:[ 0:{$matches2[1][0]}, 1:{$matches2[1][1]} ]";
}
$result = '[ ' . implode(', ', $parts) . '] ';
echo $result;
```

```
[ 0:[ 0:Spring, 1:>30 ], 1:[ 0:JPA, 1:>30 ], 2:[ 0:Hibernate, 1:>30 ]]
```

### Update

As you commented you would like valid json you can do like this if you dont want each pair to be an array.

```
$string  = "['Spring', '>30'], ['JPA', '>30'], ['Hibernate', '>30'], 1";
$matches = [];
$parts = [];
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $match) {
    $matches2 = [];
    preg_match_all('/\'(.*?)\'/', $match, $matches2);
    $parts[$matches2[1][0]] = $matches2[1][1];
}
$json = json_encode($parts);
echo $json;
```

```
{"Spring":">30","JPA":">30","Hibernate":">30"}
```

or change the $parts line with

```
$parts[] = [$matches2[1][0] => $matches2[1][1]];
```

to get

```
[{"Spring":">30"},{"JPA":">30"},{"Hibernate":">30"}]
```

Comment: thanks but what can I change in my string to make it a valid JSON?

Comment: @Ashar See answer updated.